# Django Rest Framework get last element from database

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-queryset, endpoint

I think it's simple but I cannot find the solution.

I want to get last element from the database. And create some endpoint for my rest.

I have some working solution:

views.py

```
class LastElementViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ElementSerializer
    # here I got the model Element type. So I can use it to get last_unix:
    last_unix = Element.objects.last().unix
    # and use it (last_unix) to get last element (Queryset type):
    queryset = Element.objects.filter(unix=last_unix)
```

But I'm pretty sure that Django provides some better solution :D

Do you have any idea how to do something like this?

Best regards!

Comment: [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) and  [`page_size`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

Comment: Without a `.order_by()`, `.last()` does not make much sense, since a database can return records in any order.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, yes, of course :)

Comment: @RossRogers what do you mean? I'm using pagination, but what do you mean referring to getting last element?

Comment: If you allow the `ordering` field in the query and the `page_size` attribute, you can do `page_size=1&ordering=-id`.   Sort by id reversed and get only one.

Comment: @RossRogers Yes sure, you are right :) Thank you both!